# vc++ create thread function compile error

Tags: multithreading, templates, visual-c++

when I create a thread:

```
hHand[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,0,_TF_conv_core,&pParam[i],0,NULL);
```

the _TF_conv_core is my thread function:

```
template <typename Dtype>
unsigned __stdcall _TF_conv_core(void* p_param)
{...}
```

there is a compile error said can't switching param 3 from "unsigned int (_cdecl*)(void*)" to "_beginthreadex_proc_type". But I have defined the __stdcall, why it is "_cdecl"?
when I comment out the "template ", it can be compiled successfully. why?

Comment: `_TF_conv_core` is not a function, it's a function template -
 an infinite family of functions. `_TF_conv_core<SomeType>` would be a function. In other words - imagine your code compiled: what would the value of `Dtype` be?

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have do Explicit instantiation in my code: template unsigned __stdcall _TF_conv_core<float>(void*);
template unsigned __stdcall _TF_conv_core<double>(void*);  The compile error still exist. Couldn't I define a thread function as a template type? When I define the thread function as a common function, it's OK.

Comment: That still doesn't tell `_beginthreadex` which of them you want the new thread to run. No, you cannot have a function template as a thread function; but you can a particular specialization of it, as in `_beginthreadex(..., _TF_conv_core<double>, ...)`

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.